# Does elementwise matrix inequality extend to norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

The elements of $A$ and $B$ are **non-negative** and $0 \le A_{ij} \le B_{ij}$ $\forall i,j$.

Is it true that $\Vert A \Vert_p \leq \Vert B \Vert_p$ ? The norm is the operator norm induced by the usual vector $p$-norm.

This is an exercise problem from *A Brief Introduction to Numerical Analysis* by E. Tyrtyshnikov and am using the book for self-study. My intuition is that it is true, when I think of vectors with all non-negative components, but am unable to give a proof in general.

Comment: For $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ it is definitely true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator norm is given by $$||A||_p = \sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n : ||x||_p\leq 1} ||Ax||_p = \sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n:||x||\leq 1}\left(\sum_i \left|\sum_j A_{ij}x_j\right|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

First, note that since $A$ has non-negative entries the supremum is attained for vectors with nonnegative entries: indeed, if $x$ has a negative entry $x_i$ and norm at most $1$, then the vector $x'=(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},-x_i,x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)$ has $p$-norm at most $1$ and $||Ax'||\geq ||Ax||$.

If now you only consider the term $|\sum_j A_{ij}x_j|^p$ and expand it we obtain $$\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_m=p} \binom{p}{k_1,\dots,k_m} A_{i1}^{k_1}x_1^{k_1}\dots A_{im}^{k_m}x_m^{k_m}$$
and $(A_{ij}x_j)^{k_j}\leq (B_{ij}x_j)^{k_j}$ by non-negativity. This means that $|\sum_j A_{ij}x_j|^p\leq |\sum_j B_{ij}x_j|^p$. Rewind back to the original formula and we obtain $$||A||_p=\sup_{x\in\Bbb K^n : ||x||_p\leq 1} ||Ax||_p = \sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n:||x||\leq 1}\left(\sum_i \left|\sum_j A_{ij}x_j\right|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n:||x||\leq 1}\left(\sum_i \left|\sum_j B_{ij}x_j\right|^p\right)^{1/p} = ||B||_p$$
as desired.

Comment: Just to be clear, each x_i is non-negative ?

Comment: @zarathustra You have proved the property for _integer_ p. A different argument is possible to ascertain the property for real non integer $p$s.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Could you explain how to do that ?

Comment: @zarathustra: I understand it is an increasing function, but to say $a^p < b^p$, I must show $a <b$. But $a= A_{ij}x_j$ and $b= B_{ij}x_j$. Unless $x_i$ is also non-negative, I cannot say $a < b$ right ?

Comment: @zarathustra: I am not saying $x_i$ change. Suppose I consider a set of $x_i$ that are negative.Then the constant $C$ could be begative also. Then I cannot say $a<b, a^p<b^p$. Isnt that so ?

Comment: @zarathustra: I got a concrete example to explain. Suppose $a=  A_{iij}x_j = 2x_1 + 3x_2$, $b = B_{ij}x_j =  4x_1 + 7x_2$.  Suppose $p=3$. If $x_1=x_2=-1$, then $A_{iij}x_j = -5$, $ B_{iij}x_j= -11$, so $a^p \nleq b^p$

Comment: @me10240: you are absolutely right. You can actually show that the supremum is attained for vectors with non-negative entries, see my edit.

Comment: @zarathustra: It seems that the inequality $\|A\|\leq\|B\|$ holds true even under the more general assumption that $|A_{i,j}|\leq B_{i,j}$ (so entries of $A$ may be complex). However, I can't see the proof. Do you think you could modify your argument to prove it?

Comment: @Twi, We have $\|A\| \le \| | A|\|$ where $|A|$ is the elementwise absolute value.